# ODE: Integration Factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given $(4xy)dx$+$(x^2-3y)dy=0$ I conclude that an integration factor is needed. At the end of the process I get to $\ln(u(y))=-0.5\ln|y|$. Am I allowed to use $u=1/y^{0.5}$ as an integration factor, or should I compare between the two cases when $y$ is positive and vice versa.

As always, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your IF is allowable and correct. I am not sure what you have done for the rest however, so you might want to rework that again. If you add the details using the IF, maybe we can spot issues. Regards

Comment: May I know how come it's allowable? What if y is not positive? I do believe that the rest is pretty much a straightforward process which yields $2x^2*y^0.5-2y^1.5=c$, if that was your intention.

Comment: The only restriction is $y=0$ (but look at original problem - which has the same issue), otherwise imaginary. SO, just work it out using that IF and then test the result against the ODE. Regards

Comment: One more issue is that if y is negative we may have negative number inside the root operator.

Comment: SO, this is just an imaginary number, but ODEs can have imaginary roots.

Comment: Good point. Thanks.